# Subir múltiples archivos desde excel

Tags: r, excel

Necesito subir 11 libros de excel, cada uno con dos hojas, para combinarlos en un único data table.

He usado el siguiente código:

```
lista <- list.files(path ="path")
df.lista <- lapply(lista, read_excel)
tabla <- rbindlist(df.lista, idcol ="id")
```

Con esto espero generar el datatable consolidado de la primera hoja de cada uno de los 11 libros

Pero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
 Error: `path` does not exist: ‘Mexico.xlsx
```

(Los nombres de cada uno de los libros son nombres de países) pero realmente en la carpeta donde tengo los libros los archivos de excel no tienen ningún problema

También me surge la duda de que este procedimiento me importa solo la primera hoja de cada libro. Como hago para que por separado me cree otro datatable consolidados con los datos de la segunda hoja de cada libro.

Answer (score 1):

Mi idea sería hacer una función que dado el path a un archivo lea solo las hojas del libro que me interesen y las junte en un data.frame usando `rbindlist` por ejemplo
Luego puedo aplicar esa función a cada uno de los xlsx que haya en el directorio y que me devuelva una lista en la cual cada elemento sea un df de cada archivo xlsx. Y luego puedo volver a usar `rbindlist`. 
Para que sea más interactivo podría programar una selección del path, asi no tengo que guardar los xlsx en el directorio de trabajo, los puedo tener en cualquier carpeta. Entonces el código muy comentado sería:

```
library(data.table)
library(readxl)


# esta función recive la ruta abasoluta a mi archivo de interes
# y el rango de hojas que quiero leer, por ejemplo 2:5
# por defecto es la primera hoja
miFuncion2 <- function(miArchivo, sheets = 1) {
  # read_excel tiene un parametro sheet que indica la hoja a leer pero solo es el
  # numero de hoja y yo quiero que lea un rango de hojas. Debo usar lapply
  # y dejar fijo el archivo, pasandolo como parametro secundario de lapply
  # creo una función interna 
  leeXls <- function(ss, filename) {
    read_excel(filename, sheet = ss)
  }
  # leo las hojas 
  hoja1 <- lapply(sheets, leeXls, filename = miArchivo )
  # junto las hojas en un df
  datos <- rbindlist(hoja1, idcol ="id")
  datos
}

# esta funcion devuelve una lista, cada elemento se nombra
# con el nombre de archivo XLSX sin el ".xlsx" !!
readXLSXSheets <- function(path = NULL, hojas = 1:2) {
  # obtenemos el path a la carpeta de forma interactiva
  # si no proveo el path
  if (is.null(path) && interactive() ) {
    path <- choose.dir(getwd(), "Seleccione un directorio")
    # reemplazo las barras de windows que no funcionan en linux
    # así funciona en ambos
    path <- gsub("\\\\", "/", path)
  }
  # obtengo el vector de nombres de archivos xlsx 
  archivos <- list.files(path, pattern = 'xlsx')
  # obtengo la ruta completa al archivo
  lista <- paste(path, archivos, sep="/")
  # aplico lapply a la lista de archivos con la funcion que 
  # lee las hojas que interesa
  # devuelve una lista con un elemento para cada archivo 

  output <- lapply(lista, miFuncion2, sheets = hojas)
  names(output) <- gsub('.xlsx', '', archivos)
  output
}

# Ejemplo de uso: leo 2 hojas de todos los .xlsx de un directorio
# que debo seleccionar
miLista <- readXLSXSheets()
miDF <- rbindlist(miLista, idcol = "file")
```